# Main code using the Module pattern

Tags: javascript, html, design-patterns

I'm new to JS design patterns and I would like to know if i'm doing it right.
I'm developping an HTML5 [Go game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29). So naturally i separated my code into files each implementing the Module pattern.
For example, here's the board (goban) file :

```
var goban = (function() {
    var m_canvas = null,
        m_ctx = null,
        m_canvas_height = null,
        m_canvas_width = null;

    var drawLines = function(line_step, line_limit) {
        ...
    };

    var drawStars = function(first_star_coords, distance_btwn_stars, star_size) {
        ...
    };

    return {
        init: function(canvas, ctx) {
            m_canvas = canvas;
            m_ctx = ctx;
            m_canvas_width = canvas.width;
            m_canvas_height = canvas.height;

            m_ctx.beginPath();

            drawLines(30, 30);
            drawStars(120, 180, 5);

            m_ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            m_ctx.stroke();
        }
    };
})();
```

And my main code file:

```
var main = (function() {
    /* ================================================
    Variables
    =================================================== */
    var canvas = document.getElementById("goban");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    /* ================================================
    Calls
    =================================================== */
    goban.init(canvas, ctx);

    /* ================================================
    Events
    =================================================== */
    $(canvas).click(function(evt) {
        ...
    });
})();
```

Functions in the goban module will use either canvas, or ctx, or both. Other modules too. Is it a good way to do it ? Should I make my "main" code global or should I code constructors (like the "init" function) in each module ? If so, how do you add constructors to this patten ? Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: dont blindly apply patterns because you were told to. main doesnt need to be a module or a self executing function unless you actually need to export and encapsulate some stuffs.

Comment: Sadly, everything I read about this pattern describe the principle but doesn't describe how to use it. I then applied what I knew in Java (with a Main class like any other classes calling other classes), but it seemed weird, that's why i'm here and not applying blindly ;)

Comment: you dont need a main function in javascript. And you only need a module when you want some variables to be privates, since javascript has no private operator for variables. You control variable scopes with functions , that's the why of the module pattern , hiding stuffs so there is no conflict between scripts.

Comment: I guess a simple function Goban() { ... } and then var goban = new Goban(); in the main file would be better then. Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing in Goban.If you need private static variables,singleton or stuff like that , it makes sense. Usually a simple function constructor and prototypal inheritance is enough.

Comment: Use a constructor (and inheritance) only if you need multiple instances - rather unlikely here. Use a module object only if you return more than one function. Encapsulating the variables in the IEFE is fine. Most JS apps have a `main` function that gets called onDOMready, it's fine.